# Rails Nested Form with Has Many Through Association in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes, has-many-through

I'm trying to create/update some has_many association details from a nested form. I have these 3 models `Politician`, `Characteristic` & and join model `CharacteristicPoint`

```
class Politician < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :characteristics, :through => :characteristic_points
      has_many :characteristic_points
accepts_nested_attributes_for :characteristic_points
attr_accessible :characteristic_points_attributes
end

class Characteristic < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :politicians, :through => :characteristic_points
  has_many :characteristic_points

end

class CharacteristicPoint < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :characteristic_id, :politician_id, :score_obtained
  belongs_to :politicians
  belongs_to :characteristics
end
```

What I need to do is, from PoliticiansController (for existing politician) I need to save the scores for each characteristics record in the model. For example:
1) There are some characteristics in table named (C1,C2,C3) 
2) Now when I select the `score_update` action I need to present a form which loop through all the characteristics items and present a form to add scores
3) On update the same form must be populated with assigned values from step 2 and allow user to update with new records. (Currently it create duplicate entry on the views and re-create records on the `characteristic_points` table, I just don't need this to happen.)

Here is my existing code for this:

**controller**

```
 def score_card
    @politician = Politician.find(params[:id])
    @characteristics = Characteristic.roots
    @politician.characteristic_points.build
  end
  def score_card_update
    @politician = Politician.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @politician.update_attributes(params[:politician])
        format.html { redirect_to score_card_cms_politician_path(@politician), notice: 'Score card successfully updated.' }

      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }

      end
    end
  end
```

**Views**

```
<%= form_for @politician,:url => score_card_update_politician_path,:html =>{:method => :post}  do |f| %>


                <% @characteristics.each do |characteristic| %>

                        <%= f.fields_for :characteristic_points do |builder|  %>
                        <%= render 'characteristic_point_fields', :f => builder, :politician => @politician, :characteristic => characteristic %>
                        <% end %>
                <% end %> 


    <%= f.submit "Update score"%>

<% end %>
```

**_characteristic_point_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.hidden_field :characteristic_id, :value => characteristic.id %>
<%=f.label characteristic.name%>
<%= f.text_field :score_obtained %>
```

Hope this is clear, and any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at nested forms? Here is an old but good introduction: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1 also the rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/2_3_release_notes.html#nested-object-forms

Comment: It is already a nested form -`f.fields_for :characteristic_points` but yes I missed the line `accepts_nested_attributes_for :characteristic_points` on `Politician` model. (I have added this now to Politician model)Anyway with this setup I can save this form first time only. If I want to edit it, it will create duplicate records on `characteristic_points` table. All I need to find a way to update if any record already exists or create new if there are no any records.

Comment: I think this article answer your question : http://laptite.github.io/blog/2014/02/26/deep-nesting-with-has-many-through-and-a-join-model/